# Custom resource in @Resource annotations added at runtime

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb-3.0, jndi

I want to be able to do something like this in a stateless Session Bean

```
@Resource(name="mycustomthingie") private CustomClass stuff;
```

The value injected is context (speak: Thread) dependant. 
I guess this would be possible if I bind an ObjectFactory into the JNDI Context that delivers the correct Object when requested.

As I understand it for this to work I would have to add the resource to the "java:comp" JNDI context, but this is appearantly not allowed by the EE5 specification.
Is there a subcontext in which I am allowed to write or is there another way to get something similar to work ?

Thanks

Peter

Comment: what CustomClass contains? only data or behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this article](http://www.infoq.com/news/Resource-Injection-in-the-Java-E) from InfoQ that does a good job at summarizing the Resource Injection part of the [JSR-244](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=244) (I couldn't find this in one place in the spec):

> Injection is limited only to first
>   class constructs defined in the Java
>   EE platform, including:
>
> - `SessionContext` object
> - `DataSources` object
> - `UserTransaction`
> - `EntityManager` interface
> - `TimerService` interface
> - Other enterprise beans
> - Web services
> - Message queues and topics
> - Connection factories for resource adaptes
> - Environment entries limited to String, Character, Byte, Short,
>     Integer, Long, Boolean, Double, and
>     Float.
>
> The injection facilities in Java EE 5
>   do not apply to any POJO (which is
>   often criticized by the Spring
>   community) [...]

So if your `CustomClass` is not a managed component and not a simple environment entry (which doesn't seem to be the case), I don't think you can inject it.

Comment: The environemnt entries brought me to this Idea on this page: http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2EE/injection/

I was hoping something could be done with a resource ref or something like that.